# Created a new folder inside an existing local git repo. Finder shows folder, terminal ls does not

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I created a folder, that contains an eclipse project, inside an existing local git repo. This local git repo was already up to date with the remote repo on GitHub. I'm able to see the contents of the folder and the folder itself with Finder but when I run

```
    ls -a
```

or

```
     ls
```

I get nothing but the pre-existing local git content..
Weird thing is that in eclipse if I right click and view the project in the eclipse terminal, it shows up..

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Below commands should list all files. If it is still not working specify the file name with extension inside the folder.

> ls -a
>
> ls -al